# Appending DataFrame to List in Pandas, Python

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas

I have a a file of data and want to select a specific State. From there I need to return this in a list, but  there will be years that correspond to the date with missing data, so I need to replace the missing data.

I am having some issue with my code, likely something is slightly off in my for loop:

```
def stateCountAsList(filepath,state):
    import pandas as pd 
    pd.set_option('display.width',200)

    import numpy as np 

    dataFrame = pd.read_csv(filepath,header=0,sep='\t')
    df = dataFrame.iloc[0:638,:]

    dfState = df[df['State'] == state]
    yearList = range(1999,2012)
    countsList = []

    for dfState['Year'] in yearList: 
        countsList = dfState['Count']
    else: 
        countsList.append(np.nan)
    return countsList
    print countsList.tolist() 


stateCountAsList(filepath, state)
state = 'California'
```

Traceback:

```
C:\Users\Michael\workspace\UCIIntrotoPythonDA\src\Michael_Madani_week3.py:59: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  for dfState['Year'] in yearList:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\workspace\UCIIntrotoPythonDA\src\Michael_Madani_week3.py", line 67, in <module>
    stateCountAsList(filepath, state)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\workspace\UCIIntrotoPythonDA\src\Michael_Madani_week3.py", line 62, in stateCountAsList
    countsList.append(np.nan)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1466, in append
    verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 754, in concat
    copy=copy)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 805, in __init__
    raise TypeError("cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object")
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two different issues in your code:

The warning

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
```

is triggered by `for dfState['Year'] in yearList` (line 59 in your code). In this line you try to loop over a range of years (1999 to 2012), but instead you implicitely try to assign the year value to dfState['Year']. This is not a copy, but a "view" (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy), since `df = dataFrame.iloc[0:638,:]` returns a view.

But as mentioned earlier, you don't want to assign a value to the DataFrame here, only loop over years. So the for-loop should look like:

```
for year in range(1999,2012):
    ...
```

The second issue is in line 62. Here, you try to append `np.nan` to your "list" countsList - but countsList is not a list anymore, but a DataFrame!

Two lines before, you assign a `pd.Series` (`countsList = dfState['Count']`), effectively changing the type. This gives you the `TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object`

With this information you should be able to correct your loop.

As an alternative, you can get the desired result using Pandas query method (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental):

```
def stateCountAsList(filepath,state):
    import pandas as pd 
    import numpy as np 

    dataFrame = pd.read_csv(filepath,header=0,sep='\t')
    df = dataFrame.iloc[0:638,:]

    stateList = df.query("(State == @state) & (Year > 1999 < 2005").Count.tolist()

    return stateList
```

Comment: i see what you're saying about the errors, but do not understand what the work around is here. do i need to make all my dataframes to lists? in order to work on them?

Comment: No, you don't need to convert them to lists. The first error came from a wrong syntax in your for-loop. (https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop). `for x in range(3)` means that the value of `x` is `0`, `1`, `2`. So `x` gets a value. Best try your code in an interactive ipython console (line by line, without the `def`) and have a look at the result of each line.